# Microsoft CRM 2013 Webforms or MVC

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have been wondering what technology Microsoft uses to build MS Customer 2011/ 2013? Are they using web forms or mvc?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft started development of Dynamics CRM on .NET Framework version 1.1. At that time MVC did not exist. CRM was gradually migrated to the newer framework versions (the most recent is v4.0).

The point is ASP.NET/WebForms and ASP.NET/MVC are based on very different architectures. Moving to MVC would require rewriting large parts of the application. Therefore, it is not surprising that version 2013 is still based on WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of WebForms, HttpHandlers, HttpFilters and AJAX.

Comment: and also WCF, which we all love =)